# MatchQ and patterns for similar lists

Tags: pattern-matching

I can't seem to find the right set of patterns to independently match two different lists. Simplified versions of the lists are as follows:

```
list1 = {{2}, {2}, {20}, {2}, {10}}
list2 = {{2}, {2}, {2}, {2}, {2}, {2}}
```

In general, the second list will always have the same number inside the parentheses. They can have different lengths. Both will have just a single number inside the parentheses.

I am trying to find two patterns (`p1`,`p2`):

```
p1 = {{s_?NumericQ} ..};
p2 = {{_?NumericQ} ..};
```

Such that

```
{MatchQ[list1,p1],MatchQ[list1,p2],MatchQ[list2,p1],MatchQ[list2,p2]}
```

Gives

```
{True, False, False, True}
```

My test patterns give `{True, True, False, True}` instead. I'm sure the answer is easy, but I just can't get it right...

Comment: I get `{False, True, True, True}` when I evaluate your code and that is what I would have expected to get.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch sorry must've copied it down wrong!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following patterns give the required output:

```
p1 = p : {{_?NumericQ} ..} /; ! Equal @@ p
p2 = {{s_?NumericQ} ..};


MatchQ[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Tuples[{{list1, list2}, {p1, p2}}]

(*
==> {True, False, False, True}
*)
```